# Can I mark on mesh surface with Grease Pencil and have it move with animated mesh?

Tags: grease-pencil

I put GP marks on my mesh surface for reference in viewport solid mode.

But when I move my rigged mesh, the GP marks do not follow.

Is there a way I can make the marks follow with the rigged mesh?